# onselectiong date in jquery datepicker, i need to get day and month in form textfields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

on selecting date, it has to display day name like Sunday,Monday and month name like January,February in other fields.

thanks in advance,

here is my html code

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control"></p>

<input type="text" id="day" class="form-control"></p>
<input type="text" id="month" class="form-control"></p>
```

here is my js

```
<script>
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
    $('#btn').click(function(){
         var _myDate = new Date($('#datepicker').datepicker("option" , 
"dateFormat", "mm-dd-yy").val());
         var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
 "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

          $('#my_month').val(monthNames[_myDate.getMonth()]);
          $('#my_day').val(_myDate.getDay());
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Have you read the documentation and found out what event to handle? You haven't even shown us your datepicker script. There is no question here, just an aspiration. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$( function() {
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
            inline: true,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'),
                    day  = date.getDate(),
                    month = date.getMonth() + 1,
                    year =  date.getFullYear();
 var dayOfWeek = weekday[date.getUTCDay()+1];
                $("#day").val(dayOfWeek);
                $("#month").val(month);
            }

        });

    } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control">

<input type="text" id="day" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="month" class="form-control">
```